# OpenCL intermediate language info?

Tags: opencl

I cannot find anything just explaining the syntax of the intermediate language. Does anybody know of any good documentation?

Comment: What about the specification available [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/spir/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, nothing called "OpenCL intermediate language" exists. There are vendor-specific intermediate languages used by some OpenCL implementations (such as NVIDIA's [PTX](http://www.nvidia.com/content/CUDA-ptx_isa_1.4.pdf) and AMD's [IL](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/AMD_Intermediate_Language_(IL)_Specification_v2.pdf)).

There is also the "Standard Portable Intermediate Representation" ([SPIR](https://www.khronos.org/spir)) specification from Khronos which aims to be a cross-platform intermediate representation for OpenCL device code.